# OnPreRender vs Page_PreRender

Tags: asp.net

I knew about Page PreRender event and also about overriding OnPreRender, but didn't know existence of Page_PreRender method. Recently while going through this forum i found and search the difference between both but couldn't get much?

Here is my observation:

I have a page with label Label1.

Scenario 1:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "load ";
    }
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text += "OnPreRender ";
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
    private void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text += "Page_PreRender ";
    }
```

value of Lable1 would be: load OnPreRender Page_PreRender

Scenario 2:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "load ";
        }
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            Label1.Text += "OnPreRender ";
        }
        private void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text += "Page_PreRender ";
        }
```

Note the call order of base.OnPreRender(e);

value of Lable1 would be: load Page_PreRender OnPreRender

I can only say base.OnPreRender(e) is calling Page_PreRender(), but isn't it private?

Can some one please tell, what is difference between both and when to use which?
In general which one should be used?

Answer (score 6):

The `OnPreRender` method of the page is responsible for raising the `Page_PreRender` event.

Usually you should just subscribe to the `Page_PreRender` event.

If you need to do some special processing before it's safe to raise the Page_PreRender event, then you can override the OnPreRender method and do the processing before calling `base.OnPreRender(e)`.

Answer (score 4):

The `Page_` events are called when `AutoEventWireup="true"` is set for your page.  This is how you can create them and have them called without being explicitly wired up.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, can you give some reference to resource, where i can understand how both fit together in ASP .NET Page Life Cycle?